# Need to show grandchild under child under parent in Oracle Hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have a table that has a tree of state, region, district, building and classes.  Each row has a node id and a parent id.  I am using the following

```
select name, child node, parent id from tableA  
connect by prior child node = parent id
```

i get:

```
CA  
  CENTRAL REGION  
    FRESNO DISTRICT  
     ST Jim BUILDING  
     ST joe BUILDING  
     st tom BUILDING  
     st sue BUILDING  
       JIMS CLASS  
       JOES CLASS  
       TOM CLASS  
       SUE CLASS
```

Problem is that at building level all buildings are listed one after another and then all   the classes one after another.  However I want to list the building and the class it is a parent of then the next building as follows

```
 FRESNO DISTRICT  
    st jim building  
      jims class  
    st joes building  
      joes class...
```

the node id and parent id are correct it just that all children are listed for a parent then all children for that child.  it is not showing which child goes with the parent.

I want to show the tree from the top down such as CA, Central region, Fresno district, St Joe Building, Ms Mary class, Ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hierarchical ordering should be preserved, unless you use an ORDER BY without the SIBLINGS keyword.

```
select name, id, parent_id
from tableA
connect by prior id = parent_id
start with parent_id is null
order siblings by name;
```

Using this data:

```
create table tableA(id number, name varchar2(100), parent_id number);

insert into tableA
select 1 id, 'CA' name, null parent_id from dual union all
select 2, 'CENTRAL REGION', 1 from dual union all
select 3, 'FRESNO DISTRICT', 2 from dual union all
select 4, 'ST Jim BUILDING', 3 from dual union all
select 5, 'ST joe BUILDING', 3 from dual union all
select 6, 'st tom BUILDING', 3 from dual union all
select 7, 'st sue BUILDING', 3 from dual union all
select 8, 'JIMS CLASS', 4 from dual union all
select 9, 'JOES CLASS', 5 from dual union all
select 10, 'TOM CLASS', 6 from dual union all
select 11, 'SUE CLASS', 7 from dual;
```